# Jenkins redirects back to homepage after login

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I recently upgraded jenkins to the latest version (2.290) but now every time someone logs in, it redirects them back to the main homepage instead of going back to the page where the user was before they logged in.

I looked at configure security options but there's nothing of note. So I'm not really sure where else to look. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with version 2.289.1,
switching to version **2.303.1** appears to have fix the issue